# How to discover the *exact* correspondence between boto method calls and AWS service actions

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, amazon-iam

Boto is a very convenient way to use AWS services. I want to be very specific with my IAM users/groups/policies so that I can achieve fine-grained control over access. I know about the [AWS policy generator](http://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) but there are so many aws services, each with so many actions that it's always frustrating to come up with a policy that is tailored to a particular use case. It usually requires lots of wasteful trial and error which I'd like to avoid.

I'd love to see some sort of catalog that shows exactly what actions are needed for each and every boto method call. Is this wishful thinking? Or am I missing something obvious that would help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to characterize a given application is to log your AWS API calls using CloudTrail:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/cloudtrail-integration.html

Run your app through its' paces and then you'll have a log of all the IAM info you need.  You'll probably want to do this each time you upgrade Boto, as certain calls change the way they work over time (and being surprised by an IAM failure is not good news.. :-)).